# Comparing two ArrayLists - one as a subset of the other

Tags: java, arraylist, compare, subset

I know that we can use the `containsAll` method while comparing two `ArrayLists` to check if one is a subset of the other. But this is what I would like. Consider an

`ArrayList super = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

and an

`ArrayList sub1 = 1,2,3,4`

and another

`ArrayList sub2 = 2,4,6,8`.

Now, if I did

`super.containsAll(sub1)`, it would evaluate to `true` because `sub1` is contained within `super`.

If I did `super.containsAll(sub2)`, it would also evaluate to `true` because the numbers 2,4,6 and 8 are contained in `super`.

I would like to know if there's a way to check two `ArrayLists` so that `super.containsAll(sub2)` evaluates to `false` as the numbers in `sub2` don't appear in the same order in `super`.

Comment: What do you mean by order? `2` is at index 0 in `sub2` while at index 1 in `super`? Also, you can't use `super`.

Comment: @CodinginCircles, the numbers in sub2 DO appear in the same order as the numbers in super, although super has other entries in between the ones in sub2.  Also, entries in ArrayLists are not unique, so what behaviour would you want if super was { 1,2,3,4,6,8,2,4,6,8} ?

Comment: I meant, there are numbers between 2 and 4 (3), and 4 and 6 (5), and 6 and 8 (7) and so I'd like for it evaluate to false. Unless they are in the strict order of appearance in the super ArrayList, it should always evaluate to false. Another example would be sub3= 2,1. It would be true as well, but I want it to be false.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Comparator? With a Comparator, you write the equal() method and then the framework sorts, etc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can use `Collections.indexOfSublist` to do that. More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to implement it yourself. You should traverse super, and if `super(i).equals(sub2(0))`, check that the next coming items are identical to those of sub2.